# android(2.3.3) native browser problems with handlers

Tags: android, asp.net, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm currently working on asp.net website for mobile devices, using jqMobile.
If I open website in desktop browser(Chrome, Opera) or "Opera Mobile" everything work just fine, but native browser show strange behaviour:
On first login everything fine, but if I try to re-login, or refresh information on a page (via ajax request) - I recieve old results, also there no request to handlers actually sended.
(Same behaviour on android 2.3.3 emulator)

How can I force browser to send requests, to get actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile have more aggressive policy to cache some pages, so there are two ways to force it to reaload.

**One way** is to append a random number at the end of each ajax call, and call the page eg as: `/mypage?id=23&random=88374891`

This can be done automatically by jQuery using the `cache:false` on the ajax calls eg:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: FinalCall,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) 
    {
```

**Second way** is to disable any possible cache using the headers, to force the page to not stay on mobile cache but readed again. Here is a set that disable all possible cache:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-4));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
Response.Expires = 0;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Hope this help.